# How can I display an image in crystal report with fixed size ?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I successfully added an image in crystal report using the physical path but i want to fix the size of the displayed image. Any solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to process the image before you load the report.